# . (dot) in file mode

Tags: files, rhel

I `tar` a folder on windows and `untar` on RHEL machine.
`ls -l` shows a `.` in file mode and folders are in `blue + yellow background`.

```
[root@xt-storage-01 apache-tomcat-8.0.5]# ls -l
total 120
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  4096 Jul 24 11:18 bin
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  4096 Jul 24 11:18 conf
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root root  4096 Jul 24 11:18 lib
```

what's the meaning of `.` at the end of file mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It indicates that those files are with `SELinux` security context.

From `info ls`:

```
Following the file mode bits is a single character that specifies
whether an alternate access method such as an access control list
applies to the file.  When the character following the file mode
bits is a space, there is no alternate access method.  When it is
a printing character, then there is such a method.

GNU `ls' uses a `.' character to indicate a file with an SELinux
security context, but no other alternate access method.

A file with any other combination of alternate access methods is
marked with a `+' character.
```